# how to convert numerical to character in Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

The goal I want to achieve is to link two tables one created by me, one created by others

The challenge is in my table I have numerical number for example number 2, but in the other table it use character value for example character 02.

how to join the two tables?

If I convert numerical number 2 to character it will return character 2, but how to add a character 0 before character 2?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is convert the character 02 to numeric. Once it convert to numeric, it will be 2.

Comment: An even better solution is to fix the data type.